# iOS 9 App Microphone/Camera permission granted by default?

Tags: ios, authentication, permissions, camera, microphone

Developing iOS9 app with Objective-C, and encountered this strange behavior:

After several dev cycles, now if I delete my app and reinstall from Xcode onto my dev phone, Microphone and Camera permission comes enabled by default. Shouldn't the app ask for permission when first installing the app? So now I can't test the "Undetermined" status for some of the sensor's authorization.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Do you face the same problem? (Vote up if Yes :)). No I haven't heard anything back from here, and not anywhere else. I still observe the same thing on my phone too.